# nokia 5800 sensors

Tags: javascript, nokia

I would like to know if is possible to get the sensors values of a nokia 5800 through javascript.
I know that in HTML5 there is an event  `DeviceOrientationEvent` that give some values. But since nokia 5800 doesn't have HTML5 browser I would like to know if there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRuntime widgets have JavaScript APIs to access to sensor information. See the [Platform Services 1.0 Sensors API](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Web/web-apps/symbian-web-runtime/symbian-web-runtime-api-reference/platform-services-10-javascript-api-reference/platform-services-10-sensors-api.html) documentation for details. The API is available on S60 5th edition devices such as the 5800.